# Upload imagem usando Android

Tags: php, java, android

Eu implementei o pisasso para fazer download das imagens no Android. Está funcionando maravilhosamente bem.
Mas agora eu preciso fazer um método para fazer o upload de uma imagem para um servidor php.
Eu pensei em converter para base64 e fazer o upload usando a biblioteca Volley, e depois  fazer o processo reverso no php.
Essa seria a boa alternativa ou me recomendam alguma lib? Se sim, qual?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134974/upload-de-arquivos-para-o-rest-web-service-via-android?rq=1